# Adobe Animate cc HTML 5 open URL

Tags: url, html5-canvas, animate-cc

I load image into html 5 canvas in animate cc. I need to go to some URL's when I click some places in image. How to write code for open URL in new tab using Animate cc Actions panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a premade snippet of code available in the code snippets panel.
Firstly, create a movieclip on the stage and give it a name.  Then with this object selected open the code snippets panel and choose HTML5 Canvas > Actions > Click to go to web page.  This will produce a snippet like this in the actions panel:

```
this.btn.addEventListener("click", fl_ClickToGoToWebPage);

function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage() {
    window.open("http://www.adobe.com", "_blank");
}
```

Change "btn" to whatever you called your button and the url to your url of choice.  Repeat as necessary with other buttons.